# gender_select.select.select_by_value(entry['gender']) AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

so i am testing this script with selenium and i get this error everytime theres a dropdown menu and i have to select either male or female i am selecting male but its not working
i am using an excel sheet to input the values and i typed out "Male" exectly like in the html of the link i am submitting to and its not working

```
from selenium import webdriver

import pandas as pd

from idlelib import browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager import driver
from idlelib.multicall import i
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
from operator import index


df = pd.read_excel('/Users/hamudsadek/Desktop/data.xlsx')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/Users/hamudsadek/Desktop/chromedriver')



browser.get('https://dropkicks.digitalgmg.com/dk-register.php?event=dk21-nike-dunk')
 

for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]

    
    name_input = browser.find_element_by_name('full_name')
    name_input.send_keys(entry['full name'])


    email_input = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
    email_input.send_keys(entry['email'])

    time.sleep(3)
    phone_input = browser.find_element_by_name('mobile_number')
    phone_input.send_keys(str(entry['phone']))

    

    age_input = browser.find_element_by_name('age')
    age_input.send_keys(str(entry['age']))
    
    gender_select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('gender'))
    gender_select.select.select_by_value(entry['gender'])
```

Comment: So `Select(browser.find_element_by_name('gender'))` is not working for you, correct?  Everything before works?

Comment: What if you try `find_element_by_id('gender')`?

Comment: yup only that part is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gender_select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('gender'))
gender_select.select_by_value(entry['gender'])
```

just remove select from gender_select.select

you are calling the object again